# Woocommerce delete products which are "Out of stock"

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

So, as the title, my question is how I can:
Delete all products which are "*Out of stock*", not only to hide them, but to delete from the DB.
I found the following code **but it is deleting all products, not only those that are out of stock**:

```
DELETE p FROM wp_posts p WHERE p.post_type = 'product';

DELETE pm FROM wp_postmeta pm LEFT JOIN wp_posts wp ON wp.ID = pm.post_id WHERE wp.ID IS NULL;

DELETE tr FROM wp_term_relationships tr INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id) WHERE tt.taxonomy != 'link_category' AND tr.object_id NOT IN ( SELECT ID FROM wp_posts );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Products is a custom post type, you can delete "out of stock" products by selecting such products using meta query from within WordPress

However if you want to go the SQL Query way, the following query will do the job

`DELETE p FROM wp_posts p join wp_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id WHERE p.post_type = 'product' and pm.meta_key='_stock_status' and pm.meta_value='outofstock';`

Comment: that did it from the 1st time! Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
DELETE p FROM wp_posts p WHERE p.post_type = 'product' and p.id = '$post->ID';
```

**EDITED** :

```
DELETE p FROM wp_posts p join wp_postmeta m on p.ID = m.post_id WHERE p.post_type = 'product' and m.meta_key='_stock' and m.meta_value='0';
```

Comment: How this query match only out of stock products? I can see that this will delete just 1 product, even not sure that this query can be run on external file (custom file), because `$post->ID` will not be usable on separate file.

Comment: You have not mentioned much details.You need to mention that you want to use in external file.

Comment: I think that even, if I use that query, It is not matchig all products which are out of stock. What it does is to delete only current product. So, the problem is not in the file, it is in the query. Also, I did not Downvoted

Comment: Can you please try this code :
`DELETE p.id, p.post_title, p.guid, p.post_type, m.meta_key, m.meta_value
            FROM wp_posts p
            INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m
            WHERE p.id=m.post_id
            AND m.meta_key='_stock' AND m.meta_value='0' `
Change meta_value condition as per your stock order.

Comment: #1109 - Unknown table 'id' in MULTI DELETE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64988/discussion-between-rohil-phpbeginner-and-moozy).