# How to remove out of stock woocommerce products?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

As the title describes i want to delete all the out of stock products from my woocommerce eshop at the end of the day. Every day morning i import 6000 products with their images from another server and 600-700 are out of stock. So every day i upload 700 trash in my server and i have to delete manually at the end of the day cause server data limitations. I found these related questions

[How to move out of stock product to trash Woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69676673/how-to-move-out-of-stock-product-to-trash-woocommerce)

[Woocommerce delete products which are "Out of stock"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26944107/woocommerce-delete-products-which-are-out-of-stock)

but the problem is that if i run one of these sql codes in functions.php file the products can be deleted but the thumbnails and images of the products are remain in my server and i have to delete manually.

Answer (score 1):

I would prevent the out or stock products from being imported in the first place?

How are you importing these products in the first place? The import takes place, usually via a CSV which can contain as little or as much information as you require. One column is called 'In stock?' with either a value of 1 for in stock, or 0 for out of stock.

So in your import file you can just remove the products that have a value of  0 for 'In stock?' and then carry on as normal. That way no images etc will be imported.

Comment: No. This was my first thought but the file is xml and I am downloading and importing immediately and automatically  from the other server to my shop.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could import via XML. Can you still use the 'In stock' flag though? Or in the export remove out of stock products before importing into the shop. To me, the issue is the export file, as WooCommerce will just look at this file and carry on.

Comment: I cannot edit the file because it belongs to suppliers server. Maybe I can run a cron to delete the out of stock in xml before import in my server

Comment: Yeah for sure, that would be best solution. Somehow parse the XML file with out of stock products, remove them, save the new XML and then import it.